# Disable automatic html field format recognition in IE Edge browser

Tags: html, microsoft-edge

I have html table with IP (10.212.133.144) and GUID (6237be55-0e51-4a0c-9c8a-701451389736) values. IEEdge-Win10 browser applies weird hyperlink formatting on them.

This is a simplified example without any css style and IEEdge is doing an extra magic. I don't want any hyperlink auto formatting, how can I disable this behaviour? It should work without end user interaction. No other browsers do it.

Reference question but I could not compile a working solution
[Taming the automatic telephone number thing in the windows 10 edge browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31718796/taming-the-automatic-telephone-number-thing-in-the-windows-10-edge-browser)

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>

<table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" style="border: 1px solid blue;">
  <thead id="tasks_header">
  <tr>
    <th class="normal">#</th>
    <th class="normal">IP</th>
    <th class="normal">GUID</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody id="rows1">
  <tr><td>1</td><td>1.2.3.4</td><td>a8f890ee-0ff3-44af-ba53-17c173eb62d4</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2</td><td>11.22.33.44</td><td>6237be55-0e51-4a0c-9c8a-701451389736</td></tr>
  </tbody>

  <tbody id="rows2">
  <tr><td>1b</td><td>10.212.133.144</td><td>5150471e-5528-4823-88f8-4fff9e2377be</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2c</td><td>10.210.116.164</td><td>17b9dc7a-1e70-41e0-8abc-8202597930e9</td></tr>
  </tbody>

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

edit: This behaviour is seen on two separate Win10 machines already, will try more once get access to PCs.

Comment: I dropped your code into a fiddle and viewed it in Edge and don't get that behavior.

Comment: Interesting, I did jsfiddle as well (https://jsfiddle.net/kg2f22ah/) and can see an auto formatting. Checked for F12 devops and browser is profile=desktop, ua=Microsoft Edge, version 20.10240.16384.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are being recognized as phone numbers. You can disable this by adding this metatag

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"/>
```

Comment: I did try this earlier but could not get to work, must have been a typo or something. Second try works fine. Lesson learned, must add this meta field to each and every html page from now on.